# Correcting passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

> I would like to be prepared for *X*.

How can this sentence be improved to use active voice?

Comment: I'm not sure it's truly passive. If it means "I would like someone to prepare me for X," I'd call that passive, but "prepared" as the object of "be" could, I think, be a predicate adjective. Change "prepared" to "ready" and you'll see how "prepared" could be an adjective, rather than a passive verb, in this case.

Comment: ... _correcting_ passive voice?

Comment: According to various grammar-based software (grammarly, microsoft) the phrase is passive and not *active*.  I disagree that my answer was deleted and hope it will be *undeleted* as it is both a valid answer and accurate.  Also, according to what I've read, the phrase `I would like someone to prepare me for X` is not passive (again, according to software); though I'm interested to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to prepare for X.

I don't know if the above is correct, but this occurred to me immediately after posing my question (*active voice* is a challenge as passive voice comes more naturally to me).